# What is an efficient way to filter calibration images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am performing calibration as showed in [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) tutorial.

Instead of manually visualizing to decide, I want my calibration routine to decide if an image is a good fit for calibration or not, since there are a few images where the chessboard pattern detected is crooked and they might have a bad influence on the calibration.

I have around 400 images so it is not possible to visualize and decide for each image.

The following is a possible solution, but really slow considering the huge number of images.

```
def calculate_error(img_points_p, obj_points_p, rot_vectors_p, tr_vectors_p, mtx_p, dist_p):
    error_data = []
    for i in range(len(obj_points_p)):
        img_points_2, _ = cv.projectPoints(obj_points_p[i], rot_vectors_p[i], tr_vectors_p[i], mtx_p, dist_p)
        error = cv.norm(img_points_p[i], img_points_2, cv.NORM_L2) / len(img_points_2)
        error_data.append(error)
    return error_data

# perform calibration
# call calculate_error(...)
# remove from img_points (2d points in image plane) the values which correspond to value greater than 0.1 in error_data
# perform calibration again with data with only lesser values from error_data
```

Is a faster alternative to this possible? Like checking if the image is a good one right after we detect the chessboard pattern, for all images?

Comment: maybe you could use some kind of RANSAC during calibration to find inlier/outlier.

Answer (score 1):

In algorithm form:

- Run findChessboardCorners() on each image, reject those where a chessboard is not detected.
- On the survivor images, run findHomography() on the detected chessboard corners, using the RANSAC or LMEDS estimators, reject those that fail or find less than N inliers. Use a reasonable value for N, say, 16 or 36 (meaning you want to "see" the equivalent of 4x4 or 6x6 inliers. at least. Don't be too tight on the max acceptable reprojection error, since you are not correcting for lens distortion yet.

Comment: I am not too familiar with homography, does ```retval, mask = cv.findHomography(img_points[i], obj_points[i], cv.LMEDS, 16)``` work?

Comment: It may, yes, do some experimentation.